# What is the expected cutoff score for each of the category under category-based selection for the Express Entry to Canada?

Tags: canada

IRCC of Canada has announced the Express Entry category-based draws. What would be the expected CRS cutoff score for each of these categories? IRCC hasn't announced the expected cutoff score. I have searched different websites, and there is no related information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No one knows. The draws have not happened yet.

In any case, the government does not decide on a CRS score cut off for any of its draws.

The government decides on how many people to invite (for example, 500), then it invites the first 500 qualified candidates ranked based on their CRS scores.

The cutoff is simply the score of the lowest ranked candidate. So the score depends on the pool of qualified candidates at the time of each round of invitation. It is not established beforehands and although you can get a feel of how many points should be required, exact predictions are not possible.